# Cant automate webview in hybrid appium test in python

Tags: python, android, mobile, automated-tests, appium

I am trying to make a automatic test for the WEBVIEW part of my app.
I can switch to the WEBVIEW context, but I cannot find the UI elements.

```
self.driver.find_element_by_accessibility_id('StartTrainingButton').click()
time.sleep(5)

self.driver.switch_to.context('WEBVIEW')
time.sleep(10)

a = self.driver.find_element_by_id('first_name').value_of_css_property(".form-control")
print(a)
time.sleep(5)
self.driver.find_element(id, "wp-submit").click()
```

Here is the data of the textbox `first_name`:

```
input class="form-control" type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" value="" placeholder="Vorname" required=""
```

Comment: are you using an emulator or a real device?

Comment: I am using a real device right now.

Comment: Nobody got any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for you guys who might have the same problem, this is how it works for my hybrid app:

```
    self.driver.find_element_by_accessibility_id('StartTrainingButton').click()
    time.sleep(5)

    self.driver.switch_to.context('WEBVIEW')
    time.sleep(3)

    self.driver.find_element_by_id('first_name').send_keys('Test_first')
    self.driver.find_element_by_id('last_name').send_keys('Test_last')
```

As you see, easier than i thought...